# Google Sheets - Sequence Dates across a table of data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been able to use Google Sheet's `SEQUENCE` formula to provide me with sequenced dates for `Partner 1` but then the formula stops and doesn't move on to `Partner 2`.
I have tried nesting within an Google's ArrayFormula but still cannot get it to function properly.

I'd like to avoid having to do each partner manually then copying and pasting each partner below the other.

Formulas I've tried:

For creating partner repeats based on number of days

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY( REPT($L$3:$L$16&",",$Q$3:$Q$16),,2^100),","))))
```

For sequencing dates, but only does the first range

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(SEQUENCE(Q3,1,O3)))
```

CURRENT DATA

```
| Partner| Start Date| End Date | Total Days|
|:-------|:---------:|:--------:|----------:|
|Partner1|  3/1/2021 |  3/8/2021|   7       |
|Partner2|  3/1/2021 |  3/9/2021|   8       |
```

WANTED FORMAT

```
Partner     Date        
Partner 1   3/1/2021        
Partner 1   3/2/2021        
Partner 1   3/3/2021        
Partner 1   3/4/2021        
Partner 1   3/5/2021        
Partner 1   3/6/2021        
Partner 1   3/7/2021        
Partner 1   3/8/2021        
Partner 2   3/1/2021        
Partner 2   3/2/2021        
Partner 2   3/3/2021        
Partner 2   3/4/2021        
Partner 2   3/5/2021        
Partner 2   3/6/2021        
Partner 2   3/7/2021        
Partner 2   3/8/2021        
Partner 2   3/9/2021
```

Comment: Welcome. Please share the formulas you have used before.

Comment: For creating partner repeats based on number of days => =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT($L$3:$L$16&",",$Q$3:$Q$16),,2^100),","))))

For sequencing dates, but only does the first range => =ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(SEQUENCE(Q3,1,O3)))

Comment: What is in `L`, what in `Q`, what in `O`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it generally by doing a vlookup of sequence number in the cumulative sum of the days.

For partner:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(sequence(sum(D2:D),1,0),{sumif(row(D2:D),"<"&row(D2:D),D2:D),A2:A},2,true))
```

For date:

```
=ArrayFormula(to_date(sequence(sum(D2:D),1,0)
-vlookup(sequence(sum(D2:D),1,0),sumif(row(D2:D),"<"&row(D2:D),D2:D),1,true)
+vlookup(sequence(sum(D2:D),1,0),{sumif(row(D2:D),"<"&row(D2:D),D2:D),B2:B},2,true)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The 'Date' formula works great. The 'Partner' formula is not yielding the same result as in your screenshot. I've tried editing the ranges as well. It appears that in it's current form it's returning and repeating only the last value, which in this case is blank.

Comment: Partner formula is working well now! In the above formula there seems to be a ` before the < that was throwing it off. Does exactly what I need now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula

```
=INDEX({SPLIT(A2&"@"&SEQUENCE(C2-B2,1,B2),"@");
        SPLIT(A3&"@"&SEQUENCE(C3-B3,1,B3),"@");
        SPLIT(A4&"@"&SEQUENCE(C4-B4,1,B4),"@")})
```

[image]

If still having issues, please share more info.

*(do adjust ranges and locale syntax to meet your needs)*

Comment: thanks! that works great for short partner lists. is there any way to auto-increment the partner cells? for example sometimes i work with over 50 partners

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The answer by Tom works great. Glad you worked it out.